# Cover a section with full width overlay and height not including navbar

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple HTML with styles. I want each sections to have color overlays with different opacity. The overlay should be full width that covers the whole screen but not including the top navbar but in my sample working html it covers up entirely the top area also. I noticed also that when I add another section below, it will be placed at the same position with the first section.

> Every section should be in different opacity.
>
> I managed to fix it by adjusting the top by the height of the navbar.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700');
html {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/28026/pexels-photo-28026.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  color: #cccccc;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
.spacer {
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}
.primary-head {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.sub-head {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #9b9595;
  margin-top: -70px;
}
.section-one__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li>
      <a href="" title="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" title="">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="section-one">
  <div class="section-one__overlay">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <h1 class="primary-head">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-head">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the top of the overlay-class `section-one__overlay` to the height of the navbar.

```
.section-one__overlay {
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
/*-- change top --*/
top: 53px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700');
html {
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/28026/pexels-photo-28026.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
color: #cccccc;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
float: left;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
display: inline-block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {
display: none;
}
.spacer {
margin-bottom: 20%;
}
.primary-head {
font-size: 70px;
font-weight: 700;
}
.sub-head {
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #9b9595;
margin-top: -70px;
}
.section-one__overlay {
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 53px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li>
        <a href="" title="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" title="">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="section-one">
  <div class="section-one__overlay">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <h1 class="primary-head">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-head">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea buddy but I already did that. sorry I forgot to specify in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700');

html { 
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/28026/pexels-photo-28026.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

h1{
 color: #cccccc;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

.spacer {
 margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.primary-head {
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.sub-head {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #9b9595;
    margin-top: -70px;
}

.section-one__overlay {
 position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    z-index:100;
}

nav{
      z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li><a href="" title="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="section-one">
  <div class="section-one__overlay">
   <div class="spacer"></div>
   <h1 class="primary-head">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
   <h2 class="sub-head">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Please replace(.section-one__overlay) and add (nav) following code in your project

```
.section-one__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    z-index:100;
}

nav{
      z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly. thanks for that but try to add another section below and see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

is this something you want done bro?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700');
html {
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/28026/pexels-photo-28026.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
color: #cccccc;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position:relative;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
float: left;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
display: inline-block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {
display: none;
}
.spacer {
margin-bottom: 18%;
}
.primary-head {
font-size: 70px;
font-weight: 700;
}
.sub-head {
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #9b9595;
margin-top: -70px;
}
.section-one{
position:relative;
min-height:150px;
}
.section-one__overlay {
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.section-two__overlay {
rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li>
        <a href="" title="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" title="">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="section-one">
  <div class="section-one__overlay">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <h1 class="primary-head">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-head">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section-one ">
  <div class="section-one__overlay section-two__overlay">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <h1 class="primary-head">Lorem ipsum dolor.asd</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-head">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea like that. but please explain how did you do it?

Comment: what I did is I add `position:relative` to  `<div class="section-one">` so it its child that is absolute don't cover up the navbar but instead go to the top of its parent which is relative to the navbar @claudios

Comment: Yeah +1 for that. now the second one would be when I add another section below, it should be on different opacity background.

Comment: check out the Div I have added. if that is what you want done. @claudios

Comment: the second section must be in different opacity, and it should be same height as the first section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129327/discussion-between-claudios-and-rani-moreles-rubillos).

Comment: Hey click on the `continue this to chat link`